# Web browser navigation of (Chrome HTML Document (.htm)) file into new page for windows phone 7 using C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7

I am trying to navigate my page to new page with web-browser navigation to load the file,

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Eula.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
eula.loadfile();
```

In `loadfile()`, i given  string

```
filepaht = @"C:\Users\myfilename\...\EULA.htm";
webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(filepaht, UriKind.Relative));
```

but I fail to load the `Eula.htm` file in respective page, I am getting exception as `An unknown error has occurred. Error: 80004005`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't navigate through `webBrowser` to local file as `UriKind.Relative`. Try to use `UriKind.Absolute`.

WebBrowser tries to find a file with URL like this:

```
your.ap.domain/C:\Users\myfilename\...\EULA.htm
```

Of course, it is wrong and creates an error.

Comment: i changed it to Urikind.Absolute, but still i am facing the same error.I dono whether its correctly taken my local path,just i added that .htm file into my project and add it through the project by using right clicking the project->add exisitng item and simply add the file into my project, am i right what i did? still y i am facing this error.. suggest me..